# How to echo something when a Bash script ends or gets interrupted by CTRL+D

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'd like to output something when a Bash script ends executing or when it gets manually interrupted with CTRL+D by the user.

Something like this in pseudocode:

```
if exit
  echo "Goodbye! "
fi
```

Comment: Ctrl-D is EOF. It terminates stdin from a terminal. Ctrl-C interrupts a running foreground process.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I can't grasp the difference yet, hope I'll be able to learn it Googling it later.

Comment: Ctrl-D is used at the terminal when some process is reading from the keyboard. It tells the reader that there is no more input to come. If the read process is your shell, it means you have finished entering shell commands, so the shell goes away. If you are running a command, then that command moves onto the next thing, which is usually to finish, and so the shell puts up a prompt for you to enter the next command. Ctrl-C, on the other hand, explicit tells the shell to blow away any command it is running for you, which also gets you back to the prompt. The shell won't kill itself, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Near the top of your script, code:

```
trap 'echo "Goodbye!" ' EXIT
```

Comment: Thank you, `trap` was the keyword I was missing for finding how to do it.